# Ajax POST not hitting controller break point

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, razor

My ajax POST request does'nt seem to be hitting my contoller, although i have used other Ajax post requests in my application this one doesnt seem to be working.  My first throught was the datatypes within the model were not strings but other than that i can't seem to figure out why it isnt working.

Model

```
public class AppointmentViewModel
{
    public List<DTO.Appointment> appointments { get; set; }

    public DTO.Appointment appointment { get; set; }

    public int AppointmentId_Input { get; set; }

    public string AppointmentTitle_Input { get; set; }

    public string AppointmentName_Input { get; set; }

    public DateTime AppointmentStartTime_Input { get; set; }

    public DateTime AppointmentEndTime_Input { get; set; }

    public int AppointmentType_Input { get; set; }

    public List<DTO.AppointmentType> appointmentTypes { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult AddAppointment(Models.AppointmentViewModel avm)
    {
        BLL.FTSPManager fm = new BLL.FTSPManager();

        DTO.Appointment a = new DTO.Appointment()
        {
            Id = avm.AppointmentId_Input,
            Info = avm.AppointmentTitle_Input,
            Name = avm.AppointmentName_Input,
            StartTime = avm.AppointmentStartTime_Input,
            EndTime = avm.AppointmentEndTime_Input,
            type = new DTO.AppointmentType()
            {
                Id = avm.AppointmentType_Input
            }
        };

        

        return Json(avm);
    }
```

Ajax Request:

```
   $('#btnAdd').click(function () {

            var id, title, name, startTime, endTime, AppointmentType

            id = $('#hdnAppointmentId').val();
            title = $('#txtTitle').val();
            name = $('#txtName').val();
            startTime = $('#txtStartDate').val();
            endTime = $('#txtEndDate').val();
            AppointmentType = $('#drptype').val();

            var JsonData = {
                AppointmentId_Input: id,
                AppointmentTitle_Input: title,
                AppointmentName_Input: name,
                AppointmentStartTime_Input: startTime,
                AppointmentEndTime_Input: endTime,
                AppointmentType_Input: AppointmentType
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("AddAppointment", "Admin")',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify(JsonData),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {

                return false;
                }
            });
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a FormData function. I can give for you a working example:
Html code(button, without other "input" tags:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button type="button" id="dataSend">DataSend</button>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$("#dataSend").on('click', function () {
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Image', $('#file')[0].files[0]);
formData.append('Title', document.getElementById('Title').value);
formData.append('Description', document.getElementById('Description').value);
formData.append('Topic', document.getElementById('Topic').value);
formData.append('AdditionalFields', JSON.stringify(obsFields));

$.ajax({
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Collection/Create',
    data: formData,
    success: function () {
        console.log("success.");
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error.");
    },
});});
```

C# code(controller):

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(DataForm AllData)
    {   
        return RedirectToAction("Action-method", "Controller");
    }
```

C# code(model):

```
public class DataForm
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [EnumDataType(typeof(Topic))]
    public Topic? Topic { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalFields { get; set; }
}
```

Field "AdditionalFields" is a son converted and in Controller it deserialized to 'List list'.
I'm waiting for your questions.