# No Data passed to IFormFile in .Net Core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I face issue during pass data to action in controller

```
    public class LeadFile : BaseEntity
     {
    public int LeadId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public byte[] DataFiles { get; set; }  ***********

    public Lead Lead { get; set; }

}
```

My ViewModel

```
    public class LeadFileViewModel
     {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FileType { get; set; }
    public IFormFile DataFiles { get; set; }   ***********

    }
```

And I use this extension to convert from IFileForm to byte[]

```
    public static class FormFileExtensions
     {
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this IFormFile formFile)
       {
          using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
          {
             formFile.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
          }
      }
     }
```

And this is my View

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddFileTempItem", "Leads", FormMethod.Post, new
{

    id = "AddLeadFileForm",
    @enctype = "multipart/form-data",
    @data_ajax = "true",
    @data_ajax_method = "post",
    @data_ajax_update = "#FileInformatiomList",
    @data_ajax_failure = "onFailureDefault",

    @data_ajax_complete = "AddFileTempItemOnComplete"
}))
                <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="DataFiles" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="DataFiles" type="file" class="form-control" /> ***********
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" value="Add File" class="btn btn-primary" />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

And this Controller action

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddFileTempItem(LeadFileViewModel model)
    {
        List<LeadFileViewModel> models = LeadFileViewModelsList;

        models.Add(new LeadFileViewModel
        {
            Id = models.Count + 1,
            Name = model.Name,
            DataFiles = model.DataFiles,
            Description = model.Description,
            FileType = model.FileType,

        });
        LeadFileViewModelsList = models;
        return PartialView("_LeadFilesGridPartial", LeadFileViewModelsList);
    }
```

My question is when i click add button no data passed to DataFiles propert in viewModel every time null.
any one can help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: when I use normal form tag <form ....> it is working fine, but when i use Html.BeginForm it doesn't work, now I sure 100% issue from enctype  inside Html.BeginForm, also I read some articles said you can not pass file throw ajax. what can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use my previous answer in question about transmitting files by HTTP. For transmitting files (and other information in one object) to controllers I use the "FormData" type in JS.
Resource address: [Ajax POST not hitting controller break point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64101447/ajax-post-not-hitting-controller-break-point/64106828#64106828)

1st trouble:
The directive "using without curly braces!
2nd trouble:
If you work with any model class in view you should assign this class.

Below I paste code for View with right format of "using" directive:

```html
@model LeadFileViewModel;
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div class="text-center">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddFileTempItem", "Leads", FormMethod.Post, new
    {

        id = "AddLeadFileForm",
        @enctype = "multipart/form-data",
        @data_ajax = "true",
        @data_ajax_method = "post",
        @data_ajax_update = "#FileInformatiomList",
        @data_ajax_failure = "onFailureDefault",

        @data_ajax_complete = "AddFileTempItemOnComplete"
    }))
    {
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="DataFiles" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="DataFiles" type="file" class="form-control" /> 
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" value="Add File" class="btn btn-primary" />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I need reason why no data passed to solve issue.

Comment: List "LeadFileViewModelsList" is unsigned!

Comment: Method "GetBytes" is never using in the code above.

Comment: All data passed to fields in class in my sample, located above.

Comment: Issue is HTML.Begin.Form can not working with files ,I used JavaScript and working fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you send the data by a form submission? If yes, you should use `multipart/form-data` when your form includes any `<input type="file">` elements.

```
<form asp-action="AddFileTempItem" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    //...
</form
```

Comment: I update my question to see full view code, I used BeginForm HTML helper method

Comment: It can work on my side. How do you submit the form, is there a submit button?